# Jmeter : How to increase JVM heap space from Jmeter Plugin

Tags: jmeter, jvm-arguments, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-maven-plugin

I am working on Jmeter Maven Plugin. I am getting Error from jmeter while running large number of users test cases.

Error from Jmeter Logs: 2014/08/04 18:16:29 WARN  - Thread Group 1-3 - jmeter.control.GenericController - StackOverflowError detected

So it looks like low JVM , but i am not sure how to increase JVM memory from Jmeter Maven plugin.

Can some one help me to resolve this ?

Answer (score 3):

According to [the plugin github page](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Configuring-the-jvm-that-the-jmeter-process-runs-in), you set the JVM options via the project configuration file, like this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
  <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>jmeter-tests</id>
      <phase>verify</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>jmeter</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <jMeterProcessJVMSettings>
          <xms>1024</xms>
          <xmx>1024</xmx>
          <arguments>
            <argument>-Xprof</argument>
            <argument>-Xfuture</argument>
          </arguments>
        </jMeterProcessJVMSettings>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Typical reason for StackOverflowError is bad recursive call, increasing heap won't help. Do you use any scripting or looping in your test plan? If so, inspect it carefully to detect any nested calls or loops.

Comment: Thank you all for replying.

I have a test plan with Loop controller and some Loops in Bean Shell inside it for some processing. How does it create an error ?
And this error occured when i started  Load testing [large Number of Users].

Comment: I found the Issue , It was because of Jmeter IF Controller and Regular Expression Extractor in my test logic. Whenerver the Regular Expression Extractor returns null and it is sent for validating in IF controller , we get this Warning Log.